# Get keyboard scancode of char

Tags: linux, scancodes

I want to interact with a Virtualbox-VM to do an unattended install of Virtualbox-Guest-Additions. Therefore I have to send keystrokes to the VM. I'm able to do this by using the VBoxManage-API, where I send the HEX of the scancode to the VM:

```
# sends "b" to the VM
VBoxManage controlvm "$VMNAME" keyboardputscancode <HEX>
```

Now I want to send a complete command to the VM, like:

```
mount /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom0<Enter>
```

So I have to convert every single char of that string into a scancode and send it to the VM by using VBoxManage.

How do I convert these chars to the corresponding keyboard scancodes on Linux? My VM has the same keyboard mapping like my host. I'm looking for something I can use like that:

```
$ getscancode n
> 31
```

?

Comment: I just found `showkey -s`, which gives me the correct scancode. But that only works in a Terminal outside of my Window Manager, Otherwise I get `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`.

Comment: `xev` will provide the information you need, but not in such a neat format as `showkey -s` (so I'm hesitant to give it as an answer). You will need to put the cursor into the black box, then type the keys you need.

Comment: See also [Translate ascii codes to AT set 2 keyboard scancodes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250377/translate-ascii-codes-to-at-set-2-keyboard-scancodes)

Answer (score 6):

`showkey --ascii` seems to work for [most keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34524/how-to-print-keypresses-in-inputrc-format), and it does work in my GNOME Terminal.

Comment: this only works in an interactive mode. I want to get the keychar from within a script, so i can call something like `getscancode n`.

Comment: showkey --ascii does either not report the correct scancodes in my case, or doesn't report them at all, just ascii glyph, octal pseudo scancode and keycode